# Getting the correct class name from an object for sorting algorithm

Tags: c#, sorting, reflection

I'm using a reflective enumerator class to get all the derived classes from one base class type.

```
    public static Type[] GetArrayOfType<T>() where T : class
    {
        List<Type> objects = new List<Type>();

        foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)).GetTypes()
            .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
        {
            objects.Add(type);
        }

        // AlphaNumeric Sorting
        objects.Sort(AlphaNumericSort.Comparer);        // Name property is as wanted

        return objects.ToArray();
    }
```

I would like to sort the list in the same class as it is static and called before all subsequent GUI code that relies on it is called.

```
public class AlphaNumericSort : IComparer<object>
{
    static IComparer<object> comparer = new AlphaNumericSort();

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        string s1 = x.ToString();       // Gives me the FullName
        string s1a = x.GetType().Name;  // Gives me "RuntimeType"

    ...snip
```

How can I get the correct short name, or name of the class in the comparator?  I can either obtain the FullName or the object name of RuntimeType.

EDIT:

If I try deriving from Type

```
public class AlphaNumericSort : IComparer<Type>
{
    static IComparer<Type> comparer = new AlphaNumericSort();

    public int Compare(Type x, Type y)
    {
        string s1 = x.Name;
        string s2 = y.Name;
```

Then the following line

```
objects.Sort(AlphaNumericSort.Comparer);
```

Gives me

*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer' to 'System.Comparison'*

and

*The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Sort(System.Comparison)' has some invalid arguments*

EDIT 2:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerableOfType<T>(params object[] constructorArgs) where T : class, IComparable<T>
    {
        List<T> objects = new List<T>();

        foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)).GetTypes()
            .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))))
        {
            objects.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorArgs));
        }

        // AlphaNumeric Sorting
        objects.Sort(AlphaNumericSort.Comparer);   // ERROR!!!

        return objects;
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you tried - `objects.Sort(new AlphaNumericSort())` should be fine. It is unclear from your sample what is type of `AlphaNumericSort.Comparer`.

Comment: public static IComparer<Type> Comparer
        {
            get { return comparer; }
        }

Comment: objects.Sort(new AlphaNumericSort()) does not work either and gives the same errors.

Comment: Ah ok.  It's my fault for confusing similar functions.  I've added the similar function that throws the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you can't use LINQ `OrderBy` should require less code.

```
 return objects.OrderBy(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
```

You can also derive your comparer from `IComparer<Type>` instead of `IComparer<object>` (as your list is actually list of `Type` objects) and use `Name` property there without casting.

Comment: I've attempted to implement your derive from Type method and made an edit based on what problems I have encountered as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast object to Type in your comparer, and use any field of Type you want.

```
 public int Compare(object x, object y)
 {
    Type t1 = (Type)x;
```

Comment: +1 possible fix - also deriving from correct `IComparer<Type>` would be better fix.